# Randomizing with substring

Tags: java

The code I have here only manages to randomize the length, I need to randomize the string within my class createPassword. But a method does not exist that randomizes string, only integers. Anyone have any advice?

The main:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PasswordRandomizer randomizer = new PasswordRandomizer(13);
        System.out.println("Password: " + randomizer.createPassword());
        System.out.println("Password: " + randomizer.createPassword());
        System.out.println("Password: " + randomizer.createPassword());
        System.out.println("Password: " + randomizer.createPassword());
}
}
```

Class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class PasswordRandomizer {
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int length;

    public PasswordRandomizer(int length) {
        this.length=length;
        random = new Random();
    }

    public String createPassword() {
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int randomCharIndex = random.nextInt(length);
        String randomstr = alphabet.substring(randomCharIndex); 
        return randomstr;
    }
}
```

Example outputs:

```
Password: ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Password: lmnopqrstuvwxyz
Password: jklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Password: ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: And with an integer you can point into a character list and pick one and repeat...

Comment: if this is for production use, you should get help of some libraries.. you can look into `UUID.getRandomUUID();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work fine:

```
    public String createPassword() {
        StringBuilder pass = new StringBuilder();
        Random r = new Random();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
            pass.append( (char)('a' + r.nextInt('z'-'a')) );
        }
        return pass.toString();
    }
```

The idea is to exploit that `char` can be used as an `int` and converted back to a `char` (and that alphabetical chars are consecutive in the ASCII code). So you use this to get a random char:
 `minimumValue + random.nextInt(MaxValue-MinValue)`

Comment: you didn't pass `length` as method's parameter

Comment: @KenBekov in his sample code, it's a field of his main class

Comment: So you created a new class and object here?   StringBuilder pass = new StringBuilder();. Also can you explain this line   pass.append( (char)('a' + r.nextInt('z'-'a')) );

Comment: @Nebular No StringBuilder is a class in the java.lang package that is preferable to use when creating a string bit by bit, over many steps: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html. The `append(char c)` method simply adds the char `c` to the end of the string

Comment: So it is called to manipulate the characters within the string? not sure what you mean by c.

Comment: @Nebular `char c` means any `char`, `StringBuilder` is just a tool that helps you create Strings and manipulate them, simply. Don't overthink it, and read around how to manipulate `char` and `int`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections.shuffle()` to shuffle a list. You can use the same to shuffle the chars in a string. Have a look into the below code. This code will return a unique randomized string of a given string on each execution.

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("")));
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    String randomString = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining());  // Java 8
```

If all you need is some random chars, that too for purposes of security, you should use some sort of hashing. May be you can use `UUID.randomUUID()` for getting a random value, then you can hash the same to get always unique strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getPassword(int no) {
        String inputChars= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        StringBuilder salt = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (salt.length() < no) {
            int index = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * inputChars.length());
            salt.append(inputChars.charAt(index));
        }
        String password= salt.toString();
        return password;

    }
```

But I will recommend to use `java.security.SecureRandom;`
e.g.

```
private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

public String nextSessionId() {
    return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
}
```

more secure way to genarate password